# AWS S3 multipart upload in ios

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, multipart

How I can upload a file to amazon s3 using multipart. I have gone through the all the AWS site but I did not find the code for objective-c or swift.

Could you please any one share your code for understanding purpose.

Comment: Why don't you use their AWS SDK? Its lot easier than using multipart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property) document then you can write code for multi part upload.
he minimum part size for a multipart upload is 5MB.

Comment: Link is dead and the new (terrible) documentation for "Amplify" doesn't seem to cover this topic.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty You are right. Lets write some doc about it